# Estimating A Company's Profits

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I got an Algebra 2 review sheet in Math today, and this question was on it:

> A local contracting company had annual revenues of \$15 million in 2011 and \$17.2 million in 2013. Without knowing any addition information, what figure would you estimate the 2008 revenue to have been?

My teacher said that because the difference of $17.2$ and $15$ is $2.2$, you'd divid that by $2$ because that was the increase in revenue over $2$ years, then you'd use $15 - 1.1 * 3$ to get the profit from 3 years before 2011, which would give you $11.7$ (million).

What I did was was setup the equation $15 * x^2 = 17.2$ to figure out the percent it increased over 2 years. So in that equation, $x$ would end up be $1.0708252269472673$. Then I used $15 / x^3$ to find the estimated revenue in 2008, which was $12.22$ according to that equation.

My teacher thought `11.7` was correct, but I don't see how that's very accurate. Wouldn't the way involving finding the percent it increased each year be more accurate then just subtracting a fixed amount each year? If not, then why not?

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers you give will actually be close to reality. The different solutions stem from different models of growth:

You teacher assumes linear growth, i.e. $f(t) = at + b$ while you assume exponential growth, i.e. $f(t) = c\cdot a^t$.

None of the two models are "correct" (note that both of them allow infinite growth of the company). Without knowing anything about the behaviour of the company size over time, no reliable estimate can be made. What if the company was founded in 2009? Then the 2008 revenue would obviously be $0.

Comment: Thanks! But is there one way that would probably better with the limited information? I realize it's a bad question, but my teacher just pulled this out of some book so I'm wondering if there's one way that's better, incase I have questions like this in the future

Comment: @Addison The best you can do is tell your teacher that this is complete nonsense^^ - in a diplomatic way, of course. There is no "probably better" as I tried to illustrate with the exaggerated example of the company not even existing. But assuming such a fairly large revenue you could infer that it's not a startup company so you'd expect it's growth to decelerate. This would rule out an exponential model since exponential growth accelerates over time. Thus also given the magnitude of the numbers, a safe guess is that the linear interpolation might be somewhat closer to reality than exponential

Comment: ... but again **the question you were asked is not answerable in a satisfactory way**. Linear growth doesn't account for one-time effects or trends, for example. If you want to dig deeper, look at ARIMA time series analysis. That's a way to model seasonal trends and global trends and it tends to work quite well for passive processes. For company growth, it's not suitable either since marketing campaigns and market fluctuations etc. can cause revenue to behave chaotically. The teacher is basically asking you to infer a stock market price of two years ago given two more recent values. ^^